# optimize distribution evaluating

Tags: python, pytorch, distribution

Evaluating the bivariate distribution is expensive when you assign only 500 grids for each variable. Is there any way to reduce the memory usage on this? Here is a code for illustration:

```
import torch
import torch.distributions as dist
import numpy as np

def CDF_update_bivariate(mean, cov, PDF, x, y):
    asr  =  0.9
    new_dist = dist.MultivariateNormal(torch.tensor(mean), torch.tensor(cov))

    X, Y = torch.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
    grid = torch.stack((X.flatten(), Y.flatten()), dim=1)

    pdf_new = torch.exp(new_dist.log_prob(grid)).reshape(500, 500)
    weighted_sum = asr * PDF + (1 - asr) * pdf_new
    normalized_pdf = weighted_sum / torch.sum(weighted_sum) * x.size(0) * y.size(0) / ((x[-1] - x[0]) * (y[-1] - y[0]))

    cdf = torch.cumsum(torch.cumsum(normalized_pdf, dim=0), dim=1)
    normalized_cdf = cdf / cdf[-1, -1]

    return normalized_pdf, normalized_cdf

x = torch.linspace(0.1 + 1e-4, 3, 500).double()
sk_max  =  np.exp(3 * 0.01 / np.sqrt(1 - 0.8**2))
sk_min  =  np.exp(-3 * 0.01 / np.sqrt(1 - 0.8**2))
y = torch.linspace(sk_min, sk_max, 500).double()
X, Y = torch.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')

area = (x[-1] - x[0]) * (y[-1] - y[0])
PDF  = torch.full(X.shape, 1.0 / area)

cdf_x = (X - x[0]) / (x[-1] - x[0])
cdf_y = (Y - y[0]) / (y[-1] - y[0])
CDF   = cdf_x * cdf_y

mean        =  [0, 0]
cov         =  [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
PDF,CDF     =  CDF_update_bivariate(mean, cov, PDF, x, y)
```

where the distribution evaluating part is

```
    X, Y = torch.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
    grid = torch.stack((X.flatten(), Y.flatten()), dim=1)

    pdf_new = torch.exp(new_dist.log_prob(grid)).reshape(500, 500)
```